# MySQL: can AUTO_INCREMENT=some_value; be voided when create a table and insert rows?

Tags: mysql, default-value, auto-increment

I've just converted MYISAM into InnoDB. Before doing that, I've saved the table (see the code below, that was created automatically by phpMyAdmin), dropped it, changed the engine to InnoDB and created it again.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `orderid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `memberid` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
```

---and adding some rows right after creating.

My question is about AUTO_INCREMENT=34. As I understand, 34 will be the next value of orderid in the table when we insert a new row . Can AUTO_INCREMENT be voided when creating a new table and adding rows, or it's highly recommended?
Thank you.

Comment: 1. you should use int(10) instead of varchar for memberid 2. why you want to void the auto_increment?

Comment: memberid is actually a string, but thank you anyway. What about auto_increment... I don't want to void it, I'm just asking about removing "AUTO_INCREMENT=34". "`orderid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT" stays with no changes.

Comment: Yes, I have data in that table. The last (and the biggest) orderid value is 33. That's why AUTO_INCREMENT=34. Do you recommend to keep it, else indexes could be messed up? Or, MySQL will find the biggest one and start from the next one?

Comment: see zonbiehunter answer (yes, because if you have other tables that use the same id you might messup some data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `AUTO_INCREMENT=34` part and it will start after the highest value in the table, or 1 for an empty table.

> No value was specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, so MySQL
>   assigned sequence numbers automatically. You can also explicitly
>   assign NULL or 0 to the column to generate sequence numbers.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: +1. It's a known bug that mysql includes the auto_increment when doing a table dump. Check out http://melikedev.com/2011/06/01/mysql-remove-auto_increment-from-schema-dumps-mysqldump/ for more info, otherwise just do what this solution says and remove it from your table schema.